# Ignore properties marked with specific annotation

Tags: java, jackson

I have ObjectMapper instance:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

In runtime want to serialize instance of class. What is the class the program doesn't known. It's object instance of parameterized type T.

How to ignore all properties (fields and getters) which marked specified annotation (javax.persistence.Id) ?

Example:

```
public static class PojoTest {
   @Id
   public String idTest;
   public String id;
}
    
public void serialize(Object object) {
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   // TODO ignore property mark @Id annotation
   Map<Object, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(object, Map.class);
   assertFalse(map.containsKey("idTest"));
}

public void test() {
  PojoTest pojoTest = new PojoTest();
  pojoTest.id = "foo";
  pojoTest.idTest = "bar";
  serialize(pojoTest);
}
```

Comment: You can mark them transient

Comment: You also add `@JsonIgnore` to those fields.

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. See example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a new `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector` class where you can extend `hasIgnoreMarker` method:

```
static class IdIgnoreAnnotationIntrospector extends AnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public Version version() {
        return new Version(1,0,0,"Ignore @Id", "group.id", "artifact.id");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
        return hasIdAnnotation(m);
    }

    boolean hasIdAnnotation(AnnotatedMember member) {
        return member.getAnnotation(Id.class) != null;
    }
}
```

Now you need to register this introspector:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.pair(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector(), new IdIgnoreAnnotationIntrospector()));
```

Now you can ignore all fields marked with `@Id` annotation.

Comment: not working for me for some reason.

Comment: @Mr_Hmp, are you sure you have configured properly `IdIgnoreAnnotationIntrospector`? Modern complex web apps could have more than one `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Very elegant example for re-using the [`AnnotationIntrospector`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector.html) to ignore JSON-properties based on some foreign (different-purpose) annotations️. Would you advice to consider the extension-warning in linked JavaDocs, or can it be ignored in simple cases like here?

Comment: @hc_dev, do you mean a note where it is suggested to use `NopAnnotationIntrospector` class instead of `AnnotationIntrospector`? In example like this it is important to show the simplest possible solution without overcomplicating it. Most developers probably would notice it and use but to make it better I will update later the answer.

Comment: Yes, I was just asking about your opinion on that note. Now I see, you considered it and deliberately decided to use a simple example. That's wise and fine teacher's practice. Then don't over-complicate your answer - a short warning-note suffices IMO.